# Does blockchain.info show all transactions?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, blockchain.info

My client is still syncing, so I've been checking my transactions on [blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info/).  It only shows two transactions although I know I should have more than that when I search my address.  I'm new to bitcoin, so I'm not 100% sure how it works.

Comment: Your Bitcoin.org client doesn't have "an address" it has many addresses.  When you send a payment, usually what happens is "change" is returned back to your wallet, and that change goes to a new address.

Answer (score 2):

Blockchain.info should have all the transaction information for any and all transaction that were included in blocks. It usually also has a lot of information about transactions that are not a part of the block yet, but due to the nature of message propagation in the Bitcoin network, it is possible that they might not see some of them before they are a part of the blockchain.

So, if your transactions are really fresh, blockchain.info should see them, but it's not a guarantee. If they are older, it should display them correctly. And as is always the case, some errors can occur on the software side of things.

Answer (score 2):

Blockchain.info doesn't know what addresses are in your Wallet.

You can search on a single address or for a single transaction, but that won't know what your wallet balance is, however.

There is a tool in BlockChain.info/wallet that can sync your Bitcoin.org wallet with your wallet on BlockChain.info/wallet, however that requires configuring your Bitcoin.org client a certain way.  But once that is enabled, then BlockChain.info/wallet will show all the same transactions that your Bitcoin.org client will show.